# Solve a multitude of linear least square system efficiently

Tags: python, performance, numpy, linear-algebra

I have to find the best solution for >10^7 equation systems with 5 equations in 2 variables each (5 measurements to find 2 parameters with the least amount of error in a long series).
The following code (normally used to do curve fitting) does what I want:

```
#Create_example_Data
n = 100
T_Arm = np.arange(10*n).reshape(-1, 5, 2)
Erg = np.arange(5*n).reshape(-1, 5)
m = np.zeros(n)
c = np.zeros(n)
#Run
for counter in xrange(n):
     m[counter], c[counter] = np.linalg.lstsq(T_Arm[counter, :, :], 
                                              Erg[counter, :])[0]
```

Unfortunately it is too slow. Is there any way how to speed this code up significantly? I tried to vectorise it, but I did not succeed. Using the last solution as a initial guess might be a good idea as well. Using `scipy.optimize.leastsq` did not speed it up as well.

Comment: what is `Inputlen`? is it `n`?

Comment: n is the number of equation systems and equal to Inputlen, I corrected the code

Comment: i think it should be `xrange(n)` rather than `xrange(len(n))` since `n` is just an integer (100 in this case)

Comment: Sorry for that, is corrected

Comment: So the `leastsqr` for each `counter` value is independent?  No way of casting this as a larger leastsqr problem?

Comment: Could you tell us how much time it is taking to solve all those equations, and what timing would you consider acceptable? Also: I believe the best bet is to try and manipulate all these systems so that you can group them together and reduce the number of systems to solve independently...  Finally, if all else fail, you may be interested in multithreading/processing to solve them in parallel. If I'm not mistaken numpy should release the GIL so even multithreading should provide some benefits.

Comment: @hpaulj: The systems are to be solved independently, but the changes between timestep x and timestep x+1 will be small. The desired result is the result change over time.

Comment: @Bakuriu: In the moment I am using about a minute per 1e6 evaluations on this loop alone, which is not practical. I am dreaming of speed increases by a factor of 100, which I often found when using numba or vectorised numpy. Multiprocessing or using the Gpu can be an option as well, but first optimizing the code......

Comment: You don't need to separately solve the columns of Erg. It can also solve `AX = B`. Have a look at the drivers here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq

Comment: @percusse: I am not solving the columns of Erg separately, but I have a lot of Ergs. Using scipy.linalg.lstsq is not mutch different to numpy.linalg.lstsq (hope u prove me wrong on that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a sparse block matrix A which stores the (5, 2) entries of T_Arm on its diagonal, and solve AX = b where b is the vector composed of stacked entries of `Erg`. Then solve the system with scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A, b).

To construct A and b I use n=3 for visualisation purposes:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import bsr_matrix
n = 3
col = np.hstack(5 * [np.arange(10 * n / 5).reshape(n, 2)]).flatten()
array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  2.,
        3.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  3.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  4.,  5.,  4.,  5.,
        4.,  5.,  4.,  5.])

row = np.tile(np.arange(10 * n / 2), (2, 1)).T.flatten()
array([  0.,   0.,   1.,   1.,   2.,   2.,   3.,   3.,   4.,   4.,   5.,
         5.,   6.,   6.,   7.,   7.,   8.,   8.,   9.,   9.,  10.,  10.,
        11.,  11.,  12.,  12.,  13.,  13.,  14.,  14.])

A = bsr_matrix((T_Arm[:n].flatten(), (row, col)), shape=(5 * n, 2 * n))
A.toarray()
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 8,  9,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 10, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12, 13,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 14, 15,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 16, 17,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 18, 19,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 21],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 22, 23],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 24, 25],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 26, 27],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 28, 29]], dtype=int64)

b = Erg[:n].flatten()
```

And then

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr(A, b)[0]
array([  5.00000000e-01,  -1.39548109e-14,   5.00000000e-01,
         8.71088538e-16,   5.00000000e-01,   2.35398726e-15])
```

EDIT: A is not as huge in memory as it seems: more on block sparse matrices [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.bsr_matrix.html).

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: Nice thinking. But the array A consists (n*5)*(n*2) values, all of them being int64, so for n=1000 one would need 80 MB, for n=10000 8GB and so on. All these bytes need to be read and written. Perhaps using n=100 and process the data in chunks is speedier than the original solution. I will give it a try.

Comment: @Okapi575 A is not an array (I've only used A.toarray() to represent it), but a sparse matrix, so the memory consumption will be lower. I tried it to see if the implementation worked, but I confess I haven't timed it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the good idea. After timing it with n=1e5 the time consumption is >10 times longer than the original code. The memory consumption is indeed lower, as you stated

Comment: @Okapi575 well, I wasn't very optimistic. But I'll leave it here because I find the idea pretty and playing with numpy to construct A was interesting.